# jQuery getscript callback not executing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem using jQuery's getscript. It does not execute it's callback as it wouldn't even load the script (don't know if does). Loading scripts from different sources doesn't help. Calling getscript from firebug console shows info about object like:

```
Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}
```

But expanding to more doesn't say anything interesting (methods referring to jquery). What may be important is that the site uses jQuery 1.8.1 and 1.7.1 but with noconflict. I wonder what could this redyState mean and why could cause getscript fail.

Comment: Why do you want to use 2 jQuery versions in 1 website ?

Comment: `readyState` must be 4 in order for the callback to execute. 4 means complete and successful. If you want the callback to run even if it fails... maybe `$.ajaxError`?

Comment: Actually I haven't got access to the machine hosting it, my code was implemented by friend of mine. He's using older version for some gallery plugin to work.
@Brian 
I don't want callback to run even if it fails, i want to know why does it fail.

Comment: Check your network tab in console to see result returned by request. Could be just an 404 error. BTW, how do you check that the callback is not executed?

Comment: There's no 404 error, I've even used examples from jQuery doc. I set callback to alert("test"), I would see if it was executed.